# Aspherical space whose fundamental group is subgroup of the Euclidean isometry group

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, foliations

Let $M$ be a smooth, compact manifold without a boundary, with its universal covering $\tilde{M} = \mathbb{R}^n$. If there exists an injective homomorphism $h: \pi_1(M) \rightarrow O(k) \ltimes \mathbb{R}^k < {Aff}(\mathbb{R}^k)$, where $k < n$, how can we describe $M$ and $\pi_1(M)$? In particular, can we deduce that $M$ is homeomorphic to a torus, up to a finite cover?

There is a possible solution. Since $M$ is closed manifold, $\pi_1(M)$ is a finitely generated subgroup of $\Gamma(k)=O(k) \ltimes \mathbb{R}^k $. If $\pi_1(M)$ is discrete then we can apply Bieberbach theorem and deduce that $\pi_1(M)$ is virtually Abelian.

The question arose when I was contemplating a smooth codimension $k$ foliation with a transversal Euclidean structure, whose leaves are diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n-k}$. The developing map yields the homomorphism $h: \pi_1(M) \rightarrow Iso(\mathbb{R}^k)$, and I am interested in knowing whether this implies that the manifold can only be a finite quotient of a torus.

Comment: Two small comments: first, I think your semi-direct produce is the wrong way round. (Note that $\mathrm{Isom}(\mathbb{R}^k)\cong O(k)\ltimes \mathbb{R}^k$.) And second, do you really mean that $k<n$ rather than $k\leq n$? For instance, the $(3,3,3)$ triangle group is not a subgroup of the isometry group of $\mathbb{R}$ (since it has 3-torsion).

Comment: $O(k)$ has plenty of finitely generated subgroups that are not virtually abelian, including surface groups.

Comment: @YCor: yes, but the restriction $k<n$ means that doesn’t give an immediate counterexample. In its current form, the question is more like: “Can the isometry group of $k$-dimensional Euclidean space contain the fundamental group of a non-Euclidean manifold of dimension *greater than* $k$?”

Comment: Yes, some toral bundles over surfaces of arbitrary high dimension have fundamental groups embeddable in $SE(3)$. But why do you care?

Comment: @HJRW  Right. Then it is enough to observe that $\mathbf{Z}^n$ embeds into $\mathrm{SO}(2)$ for every $n$.

Comment: @HJRW Thank you for your reminder about the correct notation. Yes, I am considering $k < n$. The question arose when I was contemplating a smooth codimension k foliation with a transversal Euclidean structure. The developing map yields the homomorphism h: π_1(M) → Iso(ℝ^k), and I am interested in knowing whether this implies that the manifold can only be finite quotient of a torus .

Comment: @YCor: I think I see your point, but let me spell it out for myself just to make sure. Since $SO(3)$ contains a hyperbolic surface group and $SO(2)$ contains every $\mathbb{Z}^n$, it follows that $SO(5)$ contains $\pi_1(S\times T^n)$ for any $n$. Nice!

Comment: @HJRW Yes. Actually $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ itself contains large groups. Namely, consider an irreducible rational degree $n$ polynomial with $n$ real roots, only one of which, $r$ is positive, and $q$ the quadratic form $X^2+Y^2+rZ^2$. Then $\mathrm{SO}(q)(\mathbf{Z})$ is a dense subgroup of $\mathrm{SO}(3)$, and is also a cocompact lattice in $\mathrm{SO}(2,1)^{n-1}$ (hence virtual cohomological dimension $2n-2$, etc).

Comment: @HJRW Thanks for spelling this out — would you mind spelling out how to embed a surface group into $\operatorname{SO}(3)$ for those of us whose spelling is not as good?

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda: This paper of Breuillard--Gelander--Souto--Storm provides a reference -- https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0602635 -- although I suspect it was known long before. I think their argument is roughly this one: for each $g\in\pi_1S$, the subset of $\mathrm{Hom}(\pi_1S,SO(3))$ that kills $g$ is nowhere dense, and the result follows by the Baire category theorem. Perhaps something like YCor's argument can give an explicit arithmetic construction.